# Rich Custom Field for Custom Post type not saving

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, post-meta

I am new to creating meta boxes and I am trying to create a custom field meta box that is connected to a custom post type which is created by WooTheme Sensei (Post type = lesson). I am trying to use wp_editor, but the issue is I can't seem to get the field to save.

I have checked many similar questions here and Google a lot, trying different solutions but nothing seems to work, I must be missing something!

These are the 3 functions I am using, I tried to turn debugging on but nothing seems to stand out. Any help is appreciated!

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_educadme_related_resources_metabox' );
add_action('save_post', 'save_educadme_related_resources', 10, 2);

// Add the Custom Fields Meta Boxe
function add_educadme_related_resources_metabox() {
    add_meta_box('educadme_related_resources', 'Related Resources', 'display_educadme_related_resources', 'lesson', 'normal', 'high');
}


// The Custom Fields Meta Metabox
function display_educadme_related_resources() {
    global $post;
    // Get the resources data if its already been entered
    $educadme_resources = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Related_Resources', true);
    wp_editor( $educadme_resources, 'related-editor', array( 'textarea_name' => 'related_resources', 'media_buttons' => false ));
}

function save_educadme_related_resources(){
    // Is the user allowed to edit the post or page?
    global $post;
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
        return;
    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return;
    }
    // OK, authenticated: we need to find and save the data
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "Related_Resources", $_POST["Related_Resources"]);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter on  wp_editor is the "metabox" field id/default name and you need to put this in the "update_post_meta" for wordpress to know what to save or specify the correct textarea_name.

In display_educadme_related_resources() use:

```
$educadme_resources = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'related-editor', true);
```

And in save_educadme_related_resources() use:

```
update_post_meta($post->ID, "related-editor", $_POST["related-editor"]);
```